# stop LI onlick but want to call accept and reject button click

Tags: jquery

while click on li than want to call getchat funcation.but when click on accept and reject than also call LI click.want to stop this two times.

```
<li onclick="getchat(this,23,'ankit  patel',32565,1119)" class="<divclass="status"></div>
                                        <div class="user_image">
                                            <img width="24" height="24" class="userimagechat" src="../Contentimage/32565/profile.jpg?e13a6f42?random=1462861613328?random=1462861614562?random=1462861615403?random=1462861616392" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user_info">

                                             <span class="pull-right dt">22 minutes ago</span>
                                                <span class="name">ankit  patel<span>- ankit Diamond</span></span>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="user-chat-btn">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="accept-btn"><a class="clsaccept" onclick="acceptleadreq(this,23,32565)">Accept</a></li>
                                                <li class="reject-btn"><a class="clsreject" onclick="rejectleadreq(this,23,32565)">Reject</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
```

Comment: Wrong HTML at line 1. `<li onclick="getchat(this,23,'ankit  patel',32565,1119)" class="<divclass="status"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage click in a single function by checking the class name.
HTML :

```
                                         <span class="pull-right dt">22 minutes ago</span>
                                            <span class="name">ankit  patel<span>- ankit Diamond</span></span>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="user-chat-btn">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="accept-btn"><a class="clsaccept" >Accept</a></li>
                                            <li class="reject-btn"><a class="clsreject" >Reject</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

Javascript:

```
function getchat(obj,a,b,c,d) {
    if($(obj).hasClass('clsaccept') || $(obj).hasClass('accept-btn')) {
        acceptleadreq(obj, a, c);
        return; 
    } else if($(obj).hasClass('clsreject') || $(obj).hasClass('reject-btn')) {
        rejectleadreq(obj, a, c);
        return; 
    } else 
// Do as required


}
```